# Why does Number function STOCKH and STOCK give different results?

Tags: numbers

Why do these 2 functions give different results?

STOCK(BTC-USD,previous close)

Result: 44452.7030

STOCKH(BTC-USD,close,"Aug 7, 2021")

Result: 44555.8008

Both done on August 8.

Are they using different closing times? UTC 0 is what I think they should use.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207109

Comment: Have you read the help file entries for both? Are they the same?

Comment: I also get results similar to yours but I think both formulas above should be returning the same number as of Aug. 8. The result by STOCKH above is actually today's (Aug. 8) opening price for Bitcoin as shown on [the Yahoo! Finance trading data page for Bitcoin](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history?p=BTC-USD) (Yahoo! Finance supplies the data for these Numbers functions). I first thought this was somehow a mix-up specific to Bitcoin, perhaps for today, but the same seems to happen with other cryptos, though not with stocks. A complaint to Apple might be in order if this persists.

Comment: Yes the discrepancy is between when STOCKH gets as close price and what STOCK gets. They are not the same. They are always pretty close % wise but definitely not the same and it's across all cryptos.

Comment: Yes Solar Mike, I read both before posting this. They don't mention anything about a difference.